# Merging two data frames without duplicating metric values

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, duplicates

I have two data frames and I want to merge them by leader values, so that I can see the total runs and walks for each groups. Each leader can have multiple members in their team, but the problem that I'm having is that when I merge them, the metrics also gets duplicated over to the newly added rows.

Here is an example of the two data sets that I have:

Data set 1:

```
+-------------+-----------+------------+-------------+
| leader name | leader id | total runs | total walks |
+-------------+-----------+------------+-------------+
| ab          |        11 |          4 |           9 |
| tg          |        47 |          8 |           3 |
+-------------+-----------+------------+-------------+
```

Data set 2:

```
+-------------+-----------+--------------+-----------+
| leader name | leader id | member name  | member id |
+-------------+-----------+--------------+-----------+
| ab          |        11 | gfh          |       589 |
| ab          |        11 | tyu          |       739 |
| tg          |        47 | rtf          |       745 |
| tg          |        47 | jke          |       996 |
+-------------+-----------+--------------+-----------+
```

I want to merge the two datasets so that they become like this:

```
+-------------+-----------+--------------+------------+------------+-------------+
| leader name | leader id | member name  | member id  | total runs | total walks |
+-------------+-----------+--------------+------------+------------+-------------+
| ab          |        11 | gfh          |        589 |          4 |           9 |
| ab          |        11 | tyu          |        739 |            |             |
| tg          |        47 | rtf          |        745 |          8 |           3 |
| tg          |        47 | jke          |        996 |            |             |
+-------------+-----------+--------------+------------+------------+-------------+
```

But right now I keep getting:

```
+-------------+-----------+--------------+------------+------------+-------------+
| leader name | leader id | member name  | member id  | total runs | total walks |
+-------------+-----------+--------------+------------+------------+-------------+
| ab          |        11 | gfh          |        589 |          4 |           9 |
| ab          |        11 | tyu          |        739 |          4 |           9 |
| tg          |        47 | rtf          |        745 |          8 |           3 |
| tg          |        47 | jke          |        996 |          8 |           3 |
+-------------+-----------+--------------+------------+------------+-------------+
```

It doesn't matter if they're blank, NA's or 0's, as long as the values aren't duplicating. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do a `replace` on those 'total' columns after a left_join

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(df2, df1 ) %>%
      group_by(leadername) %>%
      mutate_at(vars(starts_with('total')), ~ replace(., row_number() > 1, NA))
# A tibble: 4 x 6
# Groups:   leadername [2]
#  leadername leaderid membername memberid totalruns totalwalks
#  <chr>         <dbl> <chr>         <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>
#1 ab               11 gfh             589         4          9
#2 ab               11 tyu             739        NA         NA
#3 tg               47 rtf             745         8          3
#4 tg               47 jke             996        NA         NA
```

---

Or without using the `group_by`

```
left_join(df2, df1 ) %>%
     mutate_at(vars(starts_with('total')), ~ 
         replace(., duplicated(leadername), NA))
```

---

Or a `base R` option is

```
out <- merge(df2, df1, all.x = TRUE)
i1 <- duplicated(out$leadername)
out[i1, c("totalruns", "totalwalks")] <- NA
out
#  leadername leaderid membername memberid totalruns totalwalks
#1         ab       11        gfh      589         4          9
#2         ab       11        tyu      739        NA         NA
#3         tg       47        rtf      745         8          3
#4         tg       47        jke      996        NA         NA
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(leadername = c("ab", "tg"), leaderid = c(11, 47
), totalruns = c(4, 8), totalwalks = c(9, 3)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))

df2 <- structure(list(leadername = c("ab", "ab", "tg", "tg"), leaderid = c(11, 
11, 47, 47), membername = c("gfh", "tyu", "rtf", "jke"), memberid = c(589, 
739, 745, 996)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: If it wanted to group by multiple columns, such as leadername and date, do I add the additional variables in `group_by` or in `left_join` within the parameter `by`?

Comment: @JaniceLuong  In the `group_by` you can add new column names `group_by(leadername, date)` and in `left_join` as well you can specify the columns to join with `by`.  Here, I didn't use the `by` as the 'df1', 'df2', column names common were automatically picked up